# EF Database first many to many with additional field

Tags: entity-framework, database-first, ef-database-first

Now this is probably a silly issue but it's giving me quite a headache.

What I'm trying to accomplish is for EF to generate 2 objects with M-M relationship.
`Material` and `Product`. 
A Product has many materials, and one material can be found in multiple products. The trick is that materials can be measured, for example, with `kg` and I need to know how much kg does one material hold in the product it's in.
Note: Materials can exist without product, product can not exist without material.

This is the initial design I've come up with but it obviously doesn't work.

```
[Material]  [Product]    [MaterialInProduct]
ID  *PK     ID  *PK      ProductID  *FK              __together these two fields are primary key          
Code        Code         MaterialID *FK              for this table
Name        Name         QuantityOfMaterialInProduct 
Price       Quantity
Unit        Unit
Quantity
```

So my question would be, how to properly add that `QuantityOfMaterialInProduct` field, since without it DBContext tool generates everything properly.

Comment: You can't have a many-to-many association when there are additional fields in the junction table. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having EF create the many-to-many association, define the MaterialInProduct entity yourself.  You can map it to have a composite key made from the ProductId and MaterialId (with associated navigation properties).  Doing it this way, you can easily add any additional fields.

You can find documentation on custom mapping [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Comment: I tried googleing some tutorials for manual mapping, but tough luck. Could you perhaps share some?

Comment: I edited my answer to link to the documentation.  Mapping composite keys is right near the top.